# SDL video rendering failed on iPhone

Tags: iphone, streaming, sdl, render

I am trying to use the [SDL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_DirectMedia_Layer) library on my iPhone app which plays video streaming media. But I have had a hard time with how SDL works on the iPhone.

After I downloaded the SDL Library via the [SDL homepage](http://www.libsdl.org/hg.php), I tested SDL on my iPhone. But I always failed (this SDL has its own test project, and I tried this).

This is the error message when I failed the test:

```
2011-11-01 18:27:31.836 testsdl[145:707] Applications are expected to have a root view controller     at the end of application launch
Platform : All tests successful (2)
SDL_RWops : All tests successful (5)
Rect : All tests successful (1)
Assert Failed!
   Blitting blending output not the same (using SDL_BLEND_*).
   Test Case 'Blit Blending Tests'
   Test Suite 'SDL_Surface'
   Last SDL error 'Couldn't open good.bmp'
SDL_Surface : Failed 1 out of 4 testcases!
```

What does this error message mean? And do I solve them?

I think the SDL library is not yet mature for iPhone. And do you know a better library for video streaming on the iPhone?